# Uniformly integrable for a random variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am trying to show that for $k>0$ and $X$ a real valued r.v. with $E[| X|^k]<\infty$, we have:
$$
\lim_{M\to\infty} E[|X|^k 1_{\{|X|>M\}}]=0
$$

I was trying to apply Holder's inequality with $p=1,q=\infty$ to the expectation to separate it into two terms, then use Markov's inequality to get a finite expectation divided by M. However, I don't think I understand the case $q=\infty$ very well.

**Question:** is there another way to solve this without Holder?

If you have any tips on how to solve this, please comment below. Thanks for helping! :D

Comment: Another way might be to use some convergence theorem for integrals.

Comment: @GEdgar $|X|^k 1_{\{|X|>M\}}$ is bounded by $|X|^k$, so I could use DCT. But I don't know how to prove that $|X|^k 1_{\{|X|>M\}}$ converges to 0 (a.s. or p.).

Comment: What can you say about $X(\omega)$ if $\lim_{M\to\infty} |X(\omega)|^k 1_{\{|X|>M\}}(\omega)=0$ fails?

Comment: @GEdgar that limit will fail only when the indicator is $1$, no matter how big $M$ is. So if the limit fails, we must have $X(\omega)=+\infty$. But then, the measure of $\{\omega\in\Omega :X(\omega)=+\infty\}$ cannot be greater than zero, because that would imply that $E( \left|X\right|^\frac{k}{2})=\infty$, a contradiction.

Comment: @GEdgar so the set where $X(\omega)=\infty$ has measure $0$. So the sequence converges a.s. and I can apply DCT to get the result. Is this right? I've been discussing this with some folks here and looks alright.

Comment: Yes... now write it down carefully.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the partition:
$$
\begin{align}
&\Omega=\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lim_{M\to\infty}\left| X(\omega)\right|^k 1_{\{\left |X(\omega)\right|>M\}}=0\right\}\cup\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lim_{M\to\infty}\left| X(\omega)\right|^k 1_{\{\left |X(\omega)\right|>M\}}\neq0\right\}\\
\end{align}
$$
Consider the set to right. A necessary condition for the limit inside it to be different than zero is that the indicator function is different than zero for infinitely many values of $M$. Since $M\to\infty$ and $X:\Omega\to\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, we must have $X(\omega)>M,\forall M$, which implies that $X(\omega)=\infty$. Thus:
$$
\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lim_{M\to\infty}\left| X(\omega)\right|^k 1_{\{\left |X(\omega)\right|>M\}}\neq0\right\}\subset\left\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)=\infty\right\}
$$
Now, if the size of that latter set is greater than zero:
$$
\begin{align}
&P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)=\infty\right\}\right)>0\\
&\implies\mathrm{E}\left(\left|X\right|^\frac{k}{2}\right)\geq \left|X(\omega)\right|^\frac{k}{2}P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)=\infty\right\}\right)=\infty
\end{align}
$$
Which contradicts the hypothesis $\mathrm{E}\left(\left|X\right|^\frac{k}{2}\right)=\infty$. So:
$$
\begin{align}
&P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)=\infty\right\}\right)=0\\
\end{align}
$$
Now using the first equation (partition):
$$
\begin{align}
1&=P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lim_{M\to\infty}\left| X(\omega)\right|^k 1_{\{\left |X(\omega)\right|>M\}}=0\right\}\right)+P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lim_{M\to\infty}\left| X(\omega)\right|^k 1_{\{\left |X(\omega)\right|>M\}}\neq0\right\}\right)\\
&\leq P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lim_{M\to\infty}\left| X(\omega)\right|^k 1_{\{\left |X(\omega)\right|>M\}}=0\right\}\right)+P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)=\infty\right\}\right)\\
&\leq P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lim_{M\to\infty}\left| X(\omega)\right|^k 1_{\{\left |X(\omega)\right|>M\}}=0\right\}\right)
\end{align}
$$
So we have that:
$$
\begin{align}
\left| X\right|^k 1_{\{\left |X\right|>M\}}\overset{a.s.}{\to}0
\end{align}
$$
Since that sequence (in $M$) is bounded by $\left|X\right|^k$, which is bounded in expectation, the Dominated Convergence theorem gives the desired result.

Comment: In principle it may happen that the limit does not exist, not only that it exists and is not zero. Thus the dichotomy at the beginning must be rephrased.

Comment: @Did indeed! thanks for pointing that out. I will correct that to account for limit different than zero, and also non existing limit.